# admin not able to search in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using search module in my drupal 7 site.But When I login as admin and search for some thing, I'm getting an error

```
"The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page."
```

It works fine if its not logged in.Why is this happening ?

Comment: Provide more information about the site - which modules are enabled? Anything that interferes with the search form? Are you using core search module? Try clearing cache or doing it on a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the Finder Module? 
http://drupal.org/project/finder

Seems like the issue queue is full of information related to that message, here is an example of one that has helpful information.

http://drupal.org/node/1383918

If you can provide some more informatoin I would be glad to help